# Create a modal with input that runs SQL without reloading page,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an HTML table that populates from a MySQL database, I am looking for a way, when the user click on a button next to a row, that a modal opens, so that they may set the price of the item the HTML row represents.

What it needs to do:

User Clicks "Set Price" button.
Modal Opens with text input field and submit button.
User Enters Price and clicks submit.
Modal closes and updates MySQL with price.

I'm sure this needs Javascript, jQuery, and Ajax, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you someplace to start.

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){
    //Get value of text field, and send data via AJAX to route
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: any suggestions on how to tell the modal which row was clicked? I need to pass the php variable `$row['id']` to be a hidden input field POSTed with the rest of the form.

Comment: I would suggest building some of it out, trying it on your own, and then posting the code when you get stuck. We can answer then.